# Knockout foreach does not display text if already exists

Tags: text, foreach, data-binding, knockout.js

I have an array with different properties. The `title` property will be duplicated but the other properties in that item will not. I need to display the `title` property in a table however only if they are not duplicates.
my code below

```
data-bind="id: 'criteria_category_item_' + Criteria_Category_ID, text: Criteria_Title"
```

the above will display text for all titles even if they already exist so i now have duplicates in my table.

How would i do this in a `foreach` ?

Answer (score 1):

there is no data-bind="id

you probably look for attr-binding:

```
data-bind="attr:{id: ...},text: ..."
```